# Get-WmiObject not handling variable as it's typed

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Im trying to get list of all computers and logged on user for each computer.

I get the list of computers, and when I query for each string returned, I can get the logged in user.

However, when I use the computer name variable to get all users - I get an error saying that my variable is unknown. I tried casting the computer name to string but that didn't help.

By the way it's the same error that comes up when I type in a wrong computer name, so it has something to do with the type of variable #item, When I print the variable out it's correct, but cannot be used inside the loop.

```
$obj = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "L*"' -Properties * | Select -ExpandProperty Name
foreach ( $item in $obj ) { 
    $itemString = $item.ToString()
    $user = Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $itemString –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName | select -expandproperty UserName -first 1
    $user = $user.SubString(8)
    write-output "Computer: $itemString Username: $user" 

}
```

```
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At N:\Foreach.ps1:4 char:13
+     $user = Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $itemString –Class Win32_Comp ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your symptom suggests that the offending target computer is simply *not available***, e.g., due to being disconnected from the network or being powered off.

Your code doesn't deal with this scenario, but is otherwise correct in terms of data types (though given that the `.Name` property is `[string]`-typed and you've used `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`, `$obj` is an array of strings already, and therefore `$item` is a single string in the `foreach` loop, there is no need for a separate `$itemString` variable obtained with `.ToString()`).

<sup>Note: I'm assuming that the `.Name` property value is sufficient to identify a computer in the `Get-WmiObject` call; if it isn't, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty DNSHostName`.</sup>

Generally, note that `Get-WmiObject`'s `-ComputerName` parameter is `[string[]]`-typed, so you can directly pass an *array* of hostnames to it.

However, regrettably, the `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances created by `Get-WmiObject` when a target computer is unavailable don't contain the offending computer name, so using a single command with later inspection of error output isn't an option (though see the `Get-CimInstance` alternative at the bottom).

With that in mind, here's a **PSv3+ loop-based solution** that **handles unavailable computers gracefully**:

```
foreach ($computer in (Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "L*"' -Properties *).Name) {
  $computerInfo = Get-WmiObject -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
  if (-not $?) { # Call failed, analyze the reason.
    if ($Error[0].Exception.HResult -eq 0x800706BA) { # unavailable
      # Merely issue a *warning*. 
      # Alternatively, collect the unavailable names in an array for later use.
      Write-Warning "Computer is unavailable: $computer"
    } else { # unexpected error, pass it through
      Write-Error $Error[0]
    }
  } else { # success
    "Computer: $($computerInfo.Name) Username: $(($computerInfo.UserName -split '\\')[-1])" 
  }
}
```

---

By contrast, **`Get-CimInstance`** - recommended instead of `Get-WmiObject` since its introduction in PSv3 - *does* add origin information to error records, so **a *single* invocation of `Get-CimInstance` is sufficient** - do note that the results are not guaranteed to arrive in the same order in which the computers were specified, but you do benefit from ***parallel* execution**.

```
# Use a single Get-CimInstance call to target all computers and
# quietly collect errors for later analysis.
$computerNames = (Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "L*"' -Properties *).Name
Get-CimInstance -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable errs `
                -ComputerName $computerNames -Class Win32_ComputerSystem |             #`
  ForEach-Object {
    "Computer: $($_.Name) Username: $(($_.UserName -split '\\')[-1])" 
  }

# Analyze the errors that occurred, if any.
$errs | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.Exception -is [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException] -and $_.CategoryInfo.Category -eq 'ConnectionError') {
    Write-Warning "Computer is unavailable: $($_.OriginInfo.PSComputerName)"
  } else { # unexpected error, pass it through
    Write-Error $_
  }
}
```